# Insert python (voice recognition text) to SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, voice-recognition

I used a voice recognition app with python where the text of what you say is saved in a file named "yourtext.txt", and I tried to connect it to a SQL Server database where the result will be added in the text file as well as in the SQL Server table `voice2text.dbo.yourtext (id, 'text1')` any help would be appreciated.

Note : I have a syntax error in the SQL command on line 19, but I don't know how to fix it...

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import pyodbc

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source :
    print("Say Something, pwease :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try :
        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
        conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=VEGA\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=voice2text;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sqlcommand = (" insert into yourtext values ('"text"')")
        cursor.execute(sqlcommand)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print(text,file = open("yourtext.txt","a"))
    except :
        print("Sorry, could not hear !")
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: what error do you get? We can't read in your mind. Which line has number 19? Stackoverflow doesn't show line numbers.

Comment: you should use `?` and `execute( "INSERT INTO yourtext VALUES (?)", (text,) )`

Comment: to connect string from variable you have to use `+` - `"INSERT...('" + text + "')"`

Comment: better assign opened file to variable to `close()` on this file - sometimes system keeps data in buffer instead of writing in file - and it save in file only when you use `close()`

Comment: using `print()` to save in file is strange idea. Why not `f = open(..)`, `f.write(text + "\n")`, `f.close()`. Of safer `with open(...) as f: f.write(text + "\n")` and it will close correctly even if there will be error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join/concatenate string from variable you have to use `+`

```
sqlcommand = " insert into yourtext values ('" + text + "')"
```

but it would be safer to use `?` and send text as argument in execute

```
execute("INSERT INTO yourtext VALUES (?)", (text,) )
```

BTW: `execute()` needs `tuple` with arguments - even if you have only one argument. And it needs comma in `(text,)` to create `tuple`. Parenthesis `()` doesn't create `tuple`. They only separate `text,` from other comma in this line.